# Switch cursor position in visual block insert mode

Tags: vim

Is there a keystroke, similar to `v_o`, to switch cursor position in visual block insert mode?

Example: `|` cursor position

```
|line1
line2
line3
```

Hit `Ctrl+v` and go down to line 3

```
line1
line2
|line3
```

Hit `I`

```
|line1
line2
line3
```

Now the cursor is back at line 1.

I want to stay the cursor in line 3.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I ask because of your `I` which makes me think you want to do a vertical edition, is it right?

Comment: @padawin Yes, that's right. E.g., add a `x` in front of each line. But instead of starting the insert at the beginning of the column selection, I'd like to start the insert at the end of the column selection.

Comment: select the block with `vip`, press `Ctrl-v`, then press `$` and finanlly press `A`. Now you are typing on visual block at the end of the line.

Comment: @SergioAraujo Your answer doesn't match my question. I want to edit at the end of the block but at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, based on your comment:

The column insertion is done in a single step. Do your selection (c-v), go down, go in insert mode (I), add your x and leave the insert mode with either `escape` or `ctrl-[`. As you quit the insert mode, the inserted text will be added on all the lines.

In any case, your cursor will go back at the beginning. If you want to bring it at the end of what has been selected, you can do it by pressing: `'>` which marks the end of the last visual selection.

EDIT: After further discussion about the need, the point is to execute a column insert on a long range.

I would do 3 splits (with `:sp`), I would resize (by dragging the statusbar of a window) the 2 top ones to show each one line (the beginning of the selection for one, and the end for the other), they will be used as reference.

Then, use the third one to do the actual manipulation, and as you will type/indent (at the beginning of the selection), you will see it change in one of your small splits and you can compare with the other one to indent to where you want.

Here is a screenshot to illustrate it (I wanted to indent from line 1 to 43 and I use my first split as a reference to indent everything on where "blandit" is, line 44), I use the first split to see the beginning, the second to see the end and the 3rd to actually do the whole manipulation:

[image: split]

Comment: "In any case, your cursor will go back at the beginning." that's exactly what I'm asking to change for. So, you are saying there is no option to switch the cursor position to start the insert at line 3, in case of my example?

Comment: If I may ask, why does it matter where you are doing the insertion in the first place, if the "x" will be added on all the lines?

Comment: Imagine you have a lot of lines, e.g. 100, and want to indent those such that they start at the same column as line 101. So I block select all 100 lines, `I` and then want to add spaces up to the beginning of line 101 which happens to be no longer in the visible range.

Comment: Ok, I might have something for you then, bear with me a sec, I edit my answer

Comment: Done, let me know!

Comment: Funny idea. Whereby I only need one additional split (`:1sp`).

Comment: Can work with one split, it is just a rough suggestion of how to reach your need :-) Feel free to accept it if it helped.